# Simple Probability: Comparing marketing campaigns with pre and post-marketing data available

Tags: probability

I have 5 campaigns and 3.000 people who took part in it, my data consists of people who took part in the campaign and then another measure 6 months later that shows how many of them converted. I want to answer the question: What is the probability that a customer is going to convert if they took part in campaign 1, 2, 3..etc.?

So, if 300 people took part in campaign 1 and 150 of them converted, then if 900 people took part in campaign 2 and 20 of them converted..etc?

I was thinking of a simple ration, like campaign1 would be 150/300, would that be a correct way to think about it?

Another approach would be thinking of it in terms of all possible outcomes, which in case of campaign1 would be 1+2+3...+300 (all possible ways 300 people could have converted) and the final probability expressed as 150/1+2+3...+300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that no one person participated in more than one campaign.

> I was thinking of a simple ration, like campaign1 would be 150/300, would that be a correct way to think about it?

Yes, this is a perfectly sensible approach. The technical way to frame this is that you're estimating the parameter of a [Bernoulli distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution), and that the estimator you're using is the maximum likelihood estimator.

A weakness of providing just these ratios, and considering them as estimates of the true probability of converting, is that this approach doesn't leave you much information about how uncertain the estimates are. (They're only estimates, after all.) You could quantify this with, for example, confidence intervals.